# If I want to use Platform.Sub.map, do I have to import it?

Tags: elm

There is no mention of this [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform-Sub#map).

When I tried, it said `Module Platform does not expose Sub`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Platform.Sub` and `Platform.Cmd` are [imported by default](https://github.com/elm-lang/core#default-imports) **as** `Sub` and `Cmd`, so you need to omit the `Platform.`-part.

It's also worth noting that `Platform`, `Platform.Sub`, and `Platform.Cmd` are all different modules, that is, if they weren't imported by default and you just imported `Platform`, you still couldn't access `Sub` and `Cmd` with the `Platform.` prefix. This is more apparent if you look at the [source](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/tree/5.1.1/src) for the core package (specifically `Platform.elm` and `Platform/`).